# Wordpress: Wrapping two posts into one div

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops, word-wrap

I'm using Foundation for a wordpress theme and I need to wrap two posts into one div with class of 'row'. The thing is I need to put div class="row" before the first post closing the the second post with div and it should repeat with every new posts.

Here is my code:

```
<?php query_posts( 'cat=2&showposts=9&orderby=date&order=DESC' ); ?>
```

```
<div <?php post_class('small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns') ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

    <?php echo '<a href="', get_permalink(), '">';
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {the_post_thumbnail();}
        else { echo '<img src="', get_template_directory_uri( 'template_directory' ), '/images/thumb-default.png','" alt="" />'; }
        echo '</a>';
    ?>

    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
    <p><?php echo get_excerpt(); ?></p>     

</div>
```

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247770/loop-through-wordpress-posts-and-wrap-each-x-post-in-a-div

Answer (score 0):

something like this i think

```
<?php
$count = 1;
$outputstring = "";
ur while loop 

if ( $count % 2 != 0 )
{
$outputstring .= " <row div>";
}

$outputstring .= "<div" . post_class('small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns'). ' id="post-'. the_ID() .'>';

    YOUR OUTPUT CODE HERE


if ( $count % 2 == 0 )
{
$outputstring .= " </end row div>";

}
$count++;


END your while loop

echo $outputstring; /// here is where u output the WHOLE thing outside of your loop
?>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I don't understand this code. I inserted it in but it didn't work.

Comment: you can't just copy and paste your code in there.. this is all pseudo code you did have to copy the same string creating formant for the rest of your output. AND actually put this within your loop